# How do I insert a row into a splayed table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to insert a row into a table:

```
`quote insert (...)
```

but I get an error:

```
ERROR: 'splay 
(operation is not yet implemented for splayed tables)
```

How can I insert a row into a splayed table?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use insert on a splayed table like that, try using [this](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB%3aKdbplusForMortals/splayed_tables#1.2.4.1_Appending_Records)